# DTD for optional elements wihout duplicates

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm looking forward for DTD, where every element in xml file is optional, but if there are more than one, there must be in right order. And there must be at least one item with no duplicates.

In this case there is not at least one

```
<!DOCTYPE mnop [
<!ELEMENT abcd      (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT efgh      (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ijkl      (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT mnop      (abcd?, efgh?, ijkl?)>
]> 
<mnop> 
</mnop>
```

In this case there can be duplicates

```
<!DOCTYPE mnop [
<!ELEMENT abcd      (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT efgh      (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ijkl      (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT mnop      (abcd?, efgh?, ijkl?)+>
]> 
<mnop> 
    <abcd>AAAAAAA</abcd>
    <abcd>AAAAAAA</abcd>
</mnop>
```

In this case (I don't know why!) but in xml can be incorrect order (DTD valid)

```
<!DOCTYPE mnop [
<!ELEMENT abcd      (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT efgh      (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ijkl      (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT mnop      ((abcd, efgh?, ijkl?) | (abcd?, efgh, ijkl?) | (abcd?, efgh?, ijkl))>
]> 
<mnop> 
    <efgh>EEEEE</efgh>
    <abcd>AAAAAAA</abcd>
    <ijkl>AAAAAAA</ijkl>
</mnop>
```

E.g. correct files:

```
<mnop> 
    <abcd>AAAAAAA</abcd>
</mnop>
```

```
<mnop> 
    <efgh>EEEEE</efgh>
    <ijkl>AAAAAAA</ijkl>
</mnop>
```

```
<mnop> 
    <ijkl>AAAAAAA</ijkl>
</mnop>
```

and every case in correct order without duplicates.
In my example I'm talking about 3 elements but in my case I have 12 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple

```
<!ELEMENT mnop      ((a, ((b, c?) | c)?) | (b, c?) | c)? >
                    -----------------------------------^ all optional
                     (----------------)    (-----)  (-) starting with a/b/c
                     recursive
```

Notice that this scries for a generator tool, written in java or python or such.
Certainly for 12 elements.

Optionality from outer to inner: `(x, (...)?)`

Alternatives would even be better.

---

Java:

```
void p(StringBuilder sb, List<String> tags) {
    if (tags.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    int n = tags.size();
    if (n == 1) {
        sb.append(tags.get(0));
        return;
    }
    sb.append('(');
    for (int starti = 0; starti < n; ++starti) {
        if (starti != 0) {
            sb.append(" | ");
        }
        if (n - starti > 1) {
            sb.append('(');
        }
        sb.append(tags.get(starti));
        if (n - starti > 1) {
            sb.append(", ");
            p(sb, tags.subList(starti + 1, n));
            sb.append("?)");
        }
    }
    sb.append(')');
}

    StringBuilder all = new StringBuilder();
    p(all, Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
    all.append('?');
    System.out.println(all);
```

> ((a, ((b, c?) | c)?) | (b, c?) | c)?

*(I did not test it.)*